# How do I get the full path to a USB drive in Windows 7 with no drive letter?

Tags: windows-7, mount, usb-storage

I plug in a Nokia C3 phone to USB and select `view files on this device`.

It shows up in the Explorer "my computer" window as Nokia C3 under "Portable Devices" but there's no drive letter associated with it.

I've read the other tips on USB and drive letters but they all involve using the disk manager, which doesn't see the drive. It's not NTFS... the properties tab describes the FS as "generic hierarchical."

I want to be able to access the contents of the mounted phone with scripts or .bat files. I don't care if it has a drive letter or not... is there some other magic path to everything visible in "my computer?"

I tried putting a .bat file on the phone root to copy on the things I want... it says the files were copied but they just end up on the C drive under `AppData\local\temp` and don't appear on the phone.

Copy and paste using explorer Windows works fine... how can I automate this?

Comment: When the device shows up like that it's probably connected as a [MTP device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol). To read/write files on an MTP device you will need software that talks over MTP, like how the old mp3 players used to have their own software to sync music. I think the answer given here shows how to make the device show up with USB storage instead of MTP though.

Answer (score 0):

Write an [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to automate the copy and paste part.

**OR** you could use **[Belvedere](http://lifehacker.com/#!341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc)** to have all data that is copied to `\AppData\local\temp\` moved to another folder of your choice, *automatically*.

Answer (score 0):

When connected to the laptop go on your phone to `Settings -> Wireless and networks -> USB utilities`. There you can press the button `Connect storage to PC`. This option selects the USB Mass storage for Android 4.1.2.

Then it assigns a drive-letter for both the phone and the SD-card separately.